Merge Go structs definition
I have many xml files generated by a legacy application, no xsd schema available. The general structure is similar, but some files may have more (or less) fields than others.
I want to parse them using Go.
With zek I can generate a go struct from an xml file. Although the zek doc says it can inference across files, this doesn't seem to work, with only 5Mb of xml files it consumes a lot of memory and nothing happens.
So I was thinking of creating a go struct for each xml file, but how could I merge them later?
Zek will output many .go files with a similar struct like this
type Dsc struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"dsc"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    C       struct {
        Text     string `xml:",chardata"`
        Audience string `xml:"audience,attr"`
        ID       string `xml:"id,attr"`
        Level    string `xml:"level,attr"`
        Did      struct {
            Text      string `xml:",chardata"`
            Unittitle struct {
                Text           string `xml:",chardata"`
                Encodinganalog string `xml:"encodinganalog,attr"`
            } `xml:"unittitle"`
        } `xml:"did"`

I need to merge them and obtain a single Dsc struct, containing all fields

Depends on what do you really mean by "merge". Go supports "embedding" whrere you basically have type E struct { ... }; type T struct { E; ... } so that T automatically contains all fields of E; any number of types can be embedded, and embedded types can themselves embed other types. So basically you could identity a set of common "field sets", define types containing them and then define file-specific types embedding necessary types of that set of "common" ones.

…and if what I wrote in my 1st comment is not what you want, I suggest you to thoroughly elaborate on what "to merge" really means for you as this is the crux of your question, and incidentally it's also the single moot point of it ;-)

I edited the question. I don't want embedding, I want a single struct that will containing all common fields and the additional contained in some of the xml

So, you mean «take N Go source code files (generated by that "zek" thing), each of which contains a struct type named Dsc, take their definitions and somehow produce another source code file containing a definition of a new type which would be a union of all the fields from all those "source" Dsc types» right? If yes, please state that in the question.

Again, if my second attempt at interpreting is correct, then yes, it's doable using the Go standard library which implements full support for parsing of Go source code, manupulating the resulting AST and generating source code from it back—see the packages go/parser, go/ast, go/printer etc there.

It sounds like this would be solved by manually creating one XML file with all the fields in it, then let the tool generate code from that. A hacky workaround, but that is the situation you are in when you have no XSD. And you kind of need that XML file anyway for testing purposes.

I like @Gimby's suggestion: the idea of replacing merging of datatypes with merging of XML files is pretty clever indeed as you might get away with using existing tools (such as xmlstarlet) instead of writing compilcated code.

Using diff I was able to catch all the differences and manually create a new XML that I will use for struct generations. I was lucky, out of 50 XML only 6 were different with minor differences.
